# If y is in subspace W, then orthogonal project of y = y itself and thus ...

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

In Linear Algebra, it is said that 
for each y and each subspace W, the vector y - (projection of y) is orthogonal to W.

But when y is in subspace W, is it still true that y - (projection of y) is orthogonal to W?

I think it is false in this situation because the orthogonal project of y is equal to y itself and they are both on W and thus y - (projection of y) is not orthogonal to W.

Thanks

Comment: Well, the difference is zero, which is orthogonal to *everything*....

Comment: oh right..I haven't thought that way :(